# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema na função **mysql_num_rows()**

> "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given"

Eu ja andei consultando outras postagens mas nenhuma conseguiu me ajudar. O PHP está assim:

```
//Sistema de paginação

$sql_select_all = "SELECT id, nome, descricao, 'empresa' as empresa, 'empresa' as tipo  
                FROM tbl_empresa
                WHERE id LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%' OR nome LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%' OR descricao LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT tbl_produto.id, tbl_produto.nome, tbl_produto.descricao, tbl_empresa.nome, 'produto' as tipo 
                FROM tbl_produto 
                JOIN tbl_empresa
                ON tbl_empresa.id = tbl_produto.tbl_empresa_id  
                WHERE tbl_produto.id LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%' OR tbl_produto.nome LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%' OR tbl_produto.descricao LIKE '%".$colname_Pesquisa."%'";

$sql_query_all = mysql_query($sql_select_all);

//O problema esta aqui
$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_query_all);
```

Ja conferi o select e ele esta me retornando o valor esperado, tanto é que mostra na página.
Percebi que 
`$total_registros` e
`$sql_query_all` não me retornam nada;

O código esta funcionando perfeitamente no meu localhost (PHP 5.3.0), porém quando passei para o servidor (PHP 5.3.29) ele apareceu esse erro. Não acredito que tenha alguma diferença entre essas versões que iria impactar assim.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei agradecido!

Comment: O erro disse que a consulta falhou, veja se aparece algum erro, `mysql_query($sql_select_all) or die(mysql_error());`. Não use função depreciadas! prefica o MySQLi ou PDO.

Comment: Passe o segundo parametro para `mysql_query`, qual pode passar parametro de `connection_link`, depois faça essa adptação: `mysql_query($sql_select_all) or die(mysql_error())` e mostre o erro para gente.

Comment: rray, te falar que odeio usar essas funções depreciadas ou versões antigas, porem estou, na verdade, concluindo um projeto de outra pessoa, que ja tinha começado nessas condições..

Comment: É uma pena mesmo, projetos legados são complicados.

Comment: juniorb2ss, funcionou! eu acabei ficando tão fixado na função mysql_num_rows() que nem percebi a questão do banco de dados direito.

Comment: Lucas use `@` antes do nome assim vc notifica a pessoa. ex: @user

Comment: @rray, pois é, é bem complicado.. hausa, Obrigado de novo, não tinha visto que marcava com @

Comment: @juniorb2ss, só para não deixar no ar, me apareceu um erro que estava sem banco de dados quando fiz as alterações que você disse. Aí eu consegui fazer as correções aqui.

Comment: @Lucas perfeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro era aqui:

```
 mysql_query($sql_select_all) or die(mysql_error())
```

Ao fazer isso consegui observar o erro no sql e corrigir.

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score -1):

Faça a seguinte alteração:

```
$ret = mysql_query($sql_select_all);
if(!$ret){
    die("Erro de conexao")
}else{
    $total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_query_all);
}
```