# Alguem ajuda: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\redesocial\login.php on line 7

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    if (isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $verifica = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
email = '$email' AND pass='$pass'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0) {
            echo "<h3>A senha ou o e-mail tão torto aí heinKK!</h3>";
        } else {
            setcookie("login",$email);
            header("Location: ./");
        }

    }
?>
```

To tentando criar um rede social como forma de aprendizado e experiência em PHP e MYSQL.

O erro que aparece é:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
 boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\redesocial\login.php on line 7
```

Já tentei por na linha `if` o seguinte argumento:

```
if (!verifica || mysqli_num_rows($verifica)<=0) {}
```

Porém, quando clica no botão de entrar, aparentemente não está sendo feita a verificação do email e password no banco de dados já que simplesmente "loga" mesmo com as caixas de login e pass vazias.

Comment: Relacionado: [Erro no MySQL “expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in”](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28184/3774)

Comment: Relacionado: [Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in \[duplicada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90125/3774)

Comment: Adicione ` or die(mysqli_error($connect))` na linha do `$verifica` para ver o erro que retorna.

Comment: Retorna isso Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

A query não retornou resultado porque esta faltando as aspas simples entre os parâmetros

Exemplo:

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from usuarios where username = '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "' and password = '" . $_SESSION['login_pass']."' ");

Att,

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, tem como ser mais clara por gentileza? :)

Comment: Tentei por assim: $verifica = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $_POST['email'] = '$email'"" AND $_POST['pass'] = '$pass'");

Mas retorna o erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi o problema.

Como o amigo ali disse, adicionar o or die(mysqli_error($connect)); no final da linha da variável $verificar. Porém, a mesma retornava o erro Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause'. O nome da coluna de pass tava password, era só isso msm. Obrigado a todos :)